# Ubuntu VirtualBox display driver?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a dell E6230, installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox. The display defaults to 600x400 showing the upper left corner of the screen. It's the only resolution that shows in the GUI.

How do I get it to a higher resolution?  The system has an Intel HD graphics 4000.

Comment: Try install VirtualBox guest additions.

Answer (score 3):

Install guest additions for virtual box.  Then you can do custom resolutions.

Manual description of guest additions
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp52109792

How to video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q84boOmiPW8